# How much light gets bent due to the gravitation attraction of an electric field?

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, visible-light, estimation

Electric field has energy so, it will attract other bodies gravitationally according to General Relativity
so light will get bent due to this gravitation attraction. Is it possible with today's technology to detect this bending of light?

Answer (score 1):

The gravitational effect of something like an electric field includes a contribution from the energy density of the field, and a contribution from the pressure or tension in the field. Sometimes these contributions can cancel each other out, so one would not necessarily expect light to be bent by the gravitation associated with an electric field. For example, parallel cylinders of light do not attract one another (at first order approximation in the weak field limit; and I suspect also in the full theory but I have not seen a calculation).

But let's suppose that some configuration of electric field might be able to produce a gravitational effect on a light beam. We can estimate the order of magnitude of such an effect, if it is there, by calculating the energy density in the electric field, given by $(1/2) \epsilon_0 E^2$. Take a field of 1 megavolt per metre, for example, in a volume of one cubic metre. The energy is then
$$
U = (1/2) \epsilon_0 E^2 V = 4\;{\rm joules}
$$
so the mass associated with this field is
$$
m = \frac{U}{c^2} = 4.9 \times 10^{-17} \; {\rm kg}
$$
This is not large enough to produce a measurable gravitational effect on anything, least of all a beam of light!

Answer (score 1):

Let's make a simple estimate. [The energy density of an electric field](http://labman.phys.utk.edu/phys222core/modules/m6/field%20energy.html) is $$\rho_E = (1/2)\epsilon_0 E^2.$$ This corresponds to a mass density $\rho = \rho_E/c^2$. If we consider a million volt per meter field across a cubic meter volume we get the density $\rho=4.9258\cdot 10^{-17}$ kg/m$^3$ - far less than the 1 kg of air in a cubic meter. If we go up to $10^{11}$ V/m where even in vacuum there starts to be breakdown (because electrons get ripped away from surfaces, creating a cascade) the density is still $4.9258\cdot 10^{-7}$ kg/m$^3$.

The angle gravitational lensing produces is about $$\alpha \approx \frac{4GM}{c^2 b}$$ where $b$ is the impact parameter (assumed to be largish compared to $4GM/c^2$). So if we try the above cubic meter with max intensity field the deviation on a laser sent one meter away is $\approx 10^{-33}$ radians. That sounds impossible to measure. By scaling up the size of the field you can eventually reach $M$ where detection is possible - roughly near planetary or stellar masses. But that requires ridiculously large fields, so it is not a practical lab experiment.